# Вывод информации из БД при прокрутке страницы

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Помогите разобраться с выводом из БД.
Есть таблица test. В таблице есть 30 записей и первоначально выводится 10 последних записей

```
message 21
message 22
message 23
message 24
message 25
message 26
message 27
message 28
message 29
message 30
```

При прокрутке страницы пытаюсь получить предыдущие записи в количестве 10 штук:

Ожидается получить следующий вывод над сообщением message 21

```
message 11
message 12
message 13
message 14
message 15
message 16
message 17
message 18
message 19
message 20
```

А получаю в действительности такой

```
message 20
message 19
message 18
message 17
message 16
message 15
message 14
message 13
message 12
message 11
```

Сам запрос к БД PDO выглядит так

```
$res = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` < ? ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10) s ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$res->execute([$_POST["id"]]); // в $_POST["id"] передается id первого сообщения (в нашем случае это message 21)
while ($record = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $arr[] = $record;
}
return array_reverse($arr);
```

Если я запрос делаю в phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` < 21 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10) s ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

То вывод показывает как нужно.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `return array_reverse($arr);` -- так и должно быть? Это костыль?

Comment: Спасибо большое.